# client cluster database synchronization with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, client-server, terracotta

I have a **Java multi client application** which uses a database shared among all clients through **Hibernate**.
I would like to know how we can guarantee the clients always have the up-to-date data from the database.

[image: multi client java application]

Even if we didn't use any sort of cache and the clients always loaded the latest data from the database the client would always store some possibly out of date data in the form of gui elements displayed or application status.

And even so the application without a cache would be extremely unresponsive.

What I would need is for the cache to be kept always up to date (through database change events which would trigger each client to hit the database) and the gui being notified when changes happened in the cache and update itself with new data arrived from the database.

I checked for **Terracotta** which seemed to be what I needed by managing cache coherence and clustering of clients but so far it looks as if Terracotta only manages distributed Map, Queue, MultiMap, ExecutorService but doesn't help in the context of Database instead it makes it possible to share a Map as a distributed cache.

Has anyone some indication of how a multi client application using a Hibernate database can guarantee data at the clients is always up to date with the database and each client notified when another client changes the database?

Answer (score 0):

About notifications in Terracotta products: have a look at [this article](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/cache-event-listeners).
About caching options in Terracotta products: have a look at [this article](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/jdbc).
May be it will help you.

Also, you can implement some sort of data-update protocol between your clients by yourself. [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) will help you going that way.

Comment: I tried JGroups but it is too complex and in the end doesn't always guarantee connection so it might disconnect while the database is ok, so I opted for polling a database table so that at least I have a single point of failure: The Database!

Comment: EHCache article: "Normally, you will want to cache the following kinds of method calls: Any queries which can be tolerate some inconsistent or out of date data" certainly not my case!

Comment: It depends on how you are updating the database: if you can run all db-updates through caching-layer then you can rely on EHcache notification, isn't it? About JGroups - it definitely bring another point of failure and additional complexity. But this approach can be handy in future when your application became bigger.